# Cannot find symbol in toString

Tags: java, cannot-find-symbol

### Problem

I am trying to create a simple `Suitcase` class that wraps some `Item`s which have a `weight`.

I created a `getTotalWeight()` method and now I want to call it in my `toString` method but I get:

> cannot find symbol

on my statement `this.items.getTotalWeight()` in the `toString` method. Why? What am I doing wrong?

### Code

Here is the code:

**Item.java**

```
public class Item {
    private int weight;
    private String name;
    
    public Item(String name, int weight) {
        this.name = name;
        this.weight = weight;
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        return this.name + " (" + this.weight + ")";
    }
    
    public int getWeight() {
        return this.weight;
    }  
}
```

**Suitcase.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Suitcase {
    private ArrayList<Item> items;

    public Suitcase() {
        this.items = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addItem(Item item) {
        this.items.add(item);
    }

    public int getTotalWeight() {
        int totalWeight = 0;
        for (Item item : items) {
            totalWeight += item.getWeight();
        }
        return totalWeight;
    }

    public String toString() {
        if (this.items.size() == 1) {
            return this.items.size() + " item (" + this.items.getTotalWeight() + " kg)";
        } else {
            return this.items.size() + " items (" + this.items.getTotalWeight() + " kg)";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation

It is just `this.getTotalWeight()` or just `getTotalWeight()`. The method belongs to your `Suitcase` class (your `this` in the context), not to the `items`, which is of type `ArrayList`.

So correct it to:

```java
public String toString() {
  if (this.items.size() == 1) {
    return this.items.size() + " item (" + this.getTotalWeight() + " kg)";
  } else {
    return this.items.size() + " items (" + this.getTotalWeight() + " kg)";
  }
}
```

Also, please never forget to add `@Override` when you override methods (such as `toString`), this gives you additional compiler help.

---

### Simplifcations

While at it, you can simplify the code a bit, like so:

```java
@Override
public String toString() {
  String itemText = items.size() == 1 ? "item" : "items";
  return "%d %s (%d kg)".formatted(items.size(), itemText, getTotalWeight());
}
```

The key changes are:

- getting rid of the code duplication, the branching should only contain the part that actually changes (i.e. `item` vs `items`)
- using ternary for readability instead of if-else
- using formatted-strings for readability
- removing the obsolete `this.` prefixes
- adding `Override`